# PostgreSQL -> SQLite: DATE_TRUNC Equivalent

Tags: sql, sqlite

Friday afternoon and I'm fried. So fellow SQL aficionado's how to take the following WHERE clause in PostgreSQL and convert it to SQLite3 without using a compiled extension:

```
WHERE
  DATE_TRUNC('day', c.start_date) <= DATE_TRUNC('day', q.date) AND
  DATE_TRUNC('day', c.end_date) >= DATE_TRUNC('day', q.date)
```

going over the date/time functions in SQLite3 it seems like they're only for string formatting. Hope I'm seeing something wrong.

Comment: As SQLite does not have a `date` data type there can't be an equivalent.

Comment: Assuming that your columns are in a format SQLite can understand as a date then maybe `date(c.start_date)` etc is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite has no data type for dates; it uses [strings or numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) instead.

To remove the time portion of a timestamp, use the [`start of day` modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
The actual function to use (`datetime()`, `julianday()`, `strftime('%s')`) depends on the format of your date values:

```
WHERE
  datetime(c.start_date, 'start of day') <= datetime(q.date, 'start of date') AND
  datetime(c.end_date,   'start of day') >= datetime(q.date, 'start of date')
```

In this case, you could just use the `date()` function because you do not care about the actual format of the result, only how it compares:

```
WHERE
  date(c.start_date) <= date(q.date) AND
  date(c.end_date)   >= date(q.date)
```

Comment: SQLite does not support `start of week` modifier so I came up with this: `date(strftime('%s', my_date) - 86400 * ((strftime('%w', my_date) + 6) % 7), 'unixepoch')`. The `+ 6) % 7` is there to make Monday the first day of the week.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't make the above method work for hours or minutes.

For these, you can hack something up using the `strftime` functionality like so:

`select datetime(strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00', 'now'));`