# Sqlite how to round the time

Tags: sql, sqlite

how to around minus and second from datetime in sqlite?

Like:

time_round(2023-10-02 23:52:51, 'sec') = 2023-10-02 23:52:00

time_round(2023-10-02 23:02:01, 'sec') = 2023-10-02 23:02:00

time_round(2023-10-02 23:02:01, 'min') = 2023-10-02 23:00:00

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579333/5193536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo of one way:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a_table (time TEXT DEFAULT CUURENT_TIMESTAMP);
WITH counter(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x + 1 FROM counter LIMIT 10)
INSERT INTO a_table SELECT datetime('now',(random() % 1234)||' seconds') FROM counter;

/* The query (see the expression used for the `roundedTime` column) */
SELECT *,
    datetime(
        time,
        '-'||strftime('%M',time)||' minutes',
        '-'||strftime('%S',time)||' seconds'
    ) AS roundedTime,
    strftime('%M',time) AS mins,
    strftime('%S',time) AS secs
FROM a_table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a_table;
```

When run the output will be something along the lines of:-

[image]

- note that data is based upon the date and time when run and that a  0 - 1233 seconds adjustment will made to each row. So every run will yield different results (probably typically with the same hour change 1234 to a larger number 3600 for up to an hours variance). The number of rows inserted as controlled by the LIMIT (10)

If the value (time) is stored as an integer (number of seconds) then you could use

```
datetime((othertime / (60 * 60)) * (60 * 60),'unixepoch') AS OtherTimeRoundedDown
```

- where the column that the value(tiem) is stored in is `othertime`
- the rounded down value being output as column `OtherTimeRoundedDown`